# Connect SharePoint Online Lists Between Separate Team Sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I am pretty new to SharePoint, Is there a way to sync or connect two lists that resided in different SharePoint Online sites?

Answer (score 0):

You can sync two lists from different sites through Microsoft Flow.

**Please following steps:**

1.Create new list named "Sync1" in the SharePoint site

2.Create new list named "Sync2" in other SharePoint site and create same columns as the "Sync1" list

[image]

3.Create a Microsoft Flow

[image]

4.Save and Test this flow

======================== **Update Answer** ===========================

**My design philosophy:**

First, automatically trigger the Flow every 5 minutes

Then, get all items in the sync1 list(Get items) and get all items in the sync2 list(Get items 2).

Then, traverse to delete all items in the sync2 list, and re-create the same items in the sync1 list in the sync2 list

Finally, run the Flow again in 5 minutes.

========================= **Updated Answer 2** ==========================

Please use the below flow:

[image]

Sync1 & Sync2:

[image]

When I delete an item in the Sync1 list, the corresponding item in the Sync2 list is also deleted.

For example, delete item: Test222.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Please allow me to test further on the understanding. Whatif someone edited Sync2 list? Or, can I set Sync2 list as Read only?

Comment: Also, while I am testing on the solution, for Apply to Each 2, are the " choice value" and "content" refer to Sync2 as well?

Comment: Hi James. For "Apply to each 2", the "Title", "Choice value" and "Content" come from Sync1(Get item).

Comment: It works!!! One last question, what is the principle of the steps? Especially Apply to each and Apply to each 2 in this instance?

Comment: Hi James. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!

Comment: Hi, I did some change in Sync1, when I deleted a line item in Sync1, the flow seems going into issue, Sync2 no longer refresh as per Sync1

Comment: This flow is executed every 5 minutes. When you operate on the Sync1 list, the Sync2 list will not synchronize immediately, it will wait for 5 minutes. In other words, the Sync2 list and the Sync1 list perform a synchronization operation every five minutes.

Comment: Hi, sorry for missing some info in the statement. I tried with Test and waited for few 5 minutes, also, deleted and re-establish both lists, the add item or delete item action performed in Sync1, it is either Sync2 not adding or  deleted wrong item.

Comment: Have you modified this flow?

Comment: I dont modify the flow, I only add or delete on Sync1 List.

Comment: Maybe let me add on, say if I delete item one by one from Sync1, Sync2 will not follow; until all items in Sync1 deleted, Sync2 not followed

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I have retested my flow. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!